# Facebook share script for blogger is no longer working and i don't know why

Tags: facebook, blogger

so i was using this blogger share script for a long time and now it just stopped working. Maybe facebook changed something i don't know maybe you could help me guys because this whole week i'm trying to find who can fix this script.. Maybe you can use it for your own sites..

put this code in the blogger template after  tag, enter app id and fill other fields but not required.
So the code:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK VIRAL SCRIPT BEGIN -->
    <style>
        #fvsbg {
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index: 99;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
        } 
        #fvsmain {
                position:fixed;
                top:200px;
                left:50%;
                margin-left:-225px;
                z-index:100;
                width:450px;
                color:#333;
                text-align:center;
                font-family:arial,sans-serif;
                font-size:13px;
                background:transparent;
                line-height:1;
                height:200px;
                display:none;
        }
        #sharebtn {
                width: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
        }
        #h1 {
                color: #FFFFFF;   
                font-size: 2em;
                margin: 0.67em 0;
                text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black
        }               
        @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {                     
                #fvsmain {
                        position:fixed;
                        top:0;
                }
        }

    </style>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

                // SETTINGS (put information inside "")
                // See this screenshot to understand separate parts: http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7468/hnk2.png

                var AppID = '000000'; // your Facebook App ID
                var link = 'http://example.blogspot.com'; // link to your blog (must be the same as app's domain)
                var title = 'bbbb'; // title of the post
                var description = 'bbbb'; //description of the post
                var picture = ''; //image link for post

                // --------


        // FACEBOOK API         

          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                // init the FB JS SDK
                FB.init({
                  appId: AppID
                });

                // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
          };

          // Load the SDK asynchronously
          (function(d, s, id){
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function feed(){
                FB.ui(
                  {
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: title,
                        link: link,
                        picture: picture,
                        description: description
                  },
                  function(response) {
                        if (response.post_id) {
                                SetCookie("FVSC","TRUE",1);
                                document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.display="none";
                                document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="none";
                        } else {
                          alert('You must share this to unlock the page!');
                        }
                  }
                );
        }

        // FB API END



        function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
         var today = new Date();
         var expire = new Date();
         if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
         expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
         document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                                         + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
        }

        function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
         var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
         var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
         if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
         if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
         var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
         if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
         return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
        }               

        window.onload=function() {
                if(ReadCookie("FVSC") == "TRUE")
                {
                        document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.display="none";
                        document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="none";
                }
                if(ReadCookie("FVSC") != "TRUE")
                {
                        document.getElementById("fvsbg").style.backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
                        document.getElementById("fvsmain").style.display="block";
                }
        };              

        if(document.URL.indexOf("blogspot") >= 0)
        {
            if(document.URL.split('.')[1] + document.URL.split('.')[2] + document.URL.split('.')[3] != 'blogspotcom/undefined')
            {
                    window.location = link + "/ncr";
            }
        }                       
        </script>

        <div id="fvsbg"></div>
        <div id="fvsmain">
                <h1 id="h1" class="center">Share to Unlock this page</h1>
                <a href="#" onclick="feed();"><img id="sharebtn" src="http://i.imgur.com/5mSP6c1.png" /></a>
        </div>  

<!-- FACEBOOK VIRAL SCRIPT END -->
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code, maybe somebody know why facebook gives me this error: "An error occurred. Please try again later." if i want to share my website.

Comment: I found that after pressing share button in the url app id is not displayed. I think the problem is with that! could somebody look into this?

Comment: What are you trying to display?

Comment: Still didn't edit? I still can't help..